# How to get information about hovered inline sprite in a TextMeshPro?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, text, text-mesh-pro

I am new to Unity And C#. Usually I can get answers online when I encountered problems, but this one I couldn't find any clue.
I know there's a way to detect text by using `TextUtilities` something like the following snippets:

```
string hoveredWord;
int wordIndex = TMP_TextUtilities.FindIntersectingWord(description, Input.mousePosition, null);

if (wordIndex != -1)
{
    hoveredWord = description.textInfo.wordInfo[wordIndex].GetWord();
    Debug.Log("hover on " + hoveredWord);
}
```

However, it can only print out words, it prints out Nothing while hovering on an inline sprite. I've also tried use `TMP_SpriteAsset`, but it doesn't seem there's a similar method as `TextUtilities`.

I'd like to make an effect [similar to what you can see in this video](https://youtu.be/2adsmi-mRaM?t=37) : at 0:37, the textbox/tooltip is triggered while the mouse is hovering on the inline sprite.

My question is, is there any ways to GET any info of inline sprites in a TextMeshPro, especially the sprite name or sprite index while hovering over it? Or is there other way that I can implement the effect by using other ways?

Comment: You can render icons directly in your TextString (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/192004/how-to-integrate-images-into-text-lines-in-unity), you could test if the Tag is enough to find with TextUtilities

Comment: Wow, that's helpful. It looks a bit advanced to me. I will try it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you struggle with implementing it, you can always post a question with what you did and what is not working (the error you get)